# Google cloud source repository - Control access to master branch

Tags: google-cloud-repository

How would one control access to the master branch in google cloud source repository so that developers don't have access to commit to master branch ?

Answer (score 2):

We don't yet have per-branch permissions, but it's definitely something we're considering for the future.

Chris Sells
PM, Google Cloud Source Repositories